# Joomla redirects wrong after POST

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, freebsd, joomla

Situation: FreeBSD 13 server with Apache 2.4 as reverse proxy on SSL.
Bastille jail with nginx on port 80 and joomla 4.04

Problem: When doing a POST within Joomla (actually any POST except the one from logging in), the update gets handled okay but it then redirects back to the original full URL without a trailing slash. This cannot, of course, be resolved at the DNS level and results in a 404.

I tried replacing nginx with apache 2.4 but the problem stays.

In the Joomla `configuration.php` file I tried several options for the `$live_url` value (including a trailing backslash) but that didn't do the trick either. (tbh I didn't see any difference if it had a value or not).

As I'm new to Joomla, I didn't found any way of debugging to see where exactly this goes wrong and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, the problem was caused by the front-facing Apache reverse proxy server, where in the http redirect to https the trailing '/' was missing.
And because joomla gives a 303 (see other) to the non-SSL version of the URL (HTTP) it was redirected by the Apache server to a non-valid URL.

Now I have to figure out why Joomla redirects to a HTTP URL and doesn't stay with relative addressing as it is behind a reverse proxy who's handling the SSL part.